# Use JavaScript Regex in R

Tags: javascript, regex, r

Trying to translate some Javascript regex solutions to extract URLs in R. IT seems like grep should be able to handle this, but I am unsure of translating from javascript to R. The documentation here is a bit fuzzy from R. Here are the regular expressions I am trying to use to extract URLs:

```
http URL: (https?)://(www.)?[^\s]+    
bitly URL: [^https?:\/\/](bitly\.com|bit.ly)[^\s]+    
www URL: \bwww.[^\s]+
```

Can anyone help in translating this to R?

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `perl=TRUE` as a parameter to your grep function: `grep(regex, vector, perl=TRUE)`. For all your regex needs you may want to check out this [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html). Hope this helps.